# Enter , onChange event on input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input type number. I Know how to call a function when enter key is pressed.

Please have a look at my code:

```
<input type="number" class="new_num" value="0">
<input type="number" class="new_num_2" value="0">

<script>
    $('.new_num').bind("enterKey",function(e) {
        alert($(".new_num").val());
    });

    $('.new_num').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $(this).trigger("enterKey");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now I need to alert the value, when user just clicks the top or down arrow of number. I wrote this code, but it didn't work:

```
$('.new_num').bind('keyup input', function(){
    $(this).trigger("enterKey");
});
```

Please help.

Also i need to do this same operation for `new_num_2`. **Do I need to duplicate the code?**

**What code do I need to write if user is using a mobile device?**

Comment: please share html too and state clearly what is your end game with that code

Comment: i already provide the html . Please check .

Comment: Up/Dtown keys appear to be `40` and `38`. Should be the same on mobile (never tested anything on mobile). Simply add the other selector to the `$(...)` call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example logs the value of currently focused input in the console. I gave them both the same `class=new_num_2` and used that to select them. This way you don't need to duplicate the code and  do this same operation for `new_num_2`.

For mobiles I think you should put a `button` after the inputs and bind this function to the click of the button .

```js
$('.new_num').on("focus", printValue);

var printValue = function (inp){
  $(inp).bind("enterKey",function(e) {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
}

$('.new_num').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    printValue(this);
    $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    $(this).unbind("enterKey");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="new_num" id="new_num_1" value="0">
<input type="number" class="new_num" id="new_num_2" value="0">
```

Comment: i cannot use input , i can use only .new_num,.new_num_2. So i need to make duplicate code ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that completely. why cant you use input.

Comment: okay. can you give them both same `class="new_num"` and different id `new_num_1` `new_num_2`.

Comment: okay see my answer now. I am not using input anymore in the javascript. can you please accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: it is good friend :) . I accepted your answer . But you forgot to answer about .new_num_2. I need to to write all code again for .new_num_2

Comment: Sorry for that. I really forgot. You don't need to do that now.

Comment: could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547257/change-morris-graph-as-per-our-requirements